# How to group rows on range when cell value is number in ag-grid-react?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to group rows according to range of numbers like < 50, 50-69,70-100, 100+ but rows are grouped according to value in a cell in each row.

I have a custom filter for the column on which i am enabling rowGroup, I have a cell renderer which renders the cell style according to the value. the cell renderer return a value or html string which is rendered in grid cell. when you enable row group the same cell renderer return the the ranges i.e <50 , 50-69, 70-100, 100+, But group count is not according to these range instead it is grouped on value of the cell.

field Definition:

```
{
          headerName:"PH Index",
          field: "botScore",
          width: 120,
          cellStyle: { textAlign : 'center', padding: '0px 0px' },
          cellRenderer: this.scoreRenderer,
          filter: "scoreFilter", 
          enableRowGroup: true,
          enablePivot: true,
          menuTabs : ['filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab', 'columnsMenuTab'],
},`
```

CellRenderer:

```
scoreRenderer(params){
    let progress;
    if(typeof(params.value)== "number"){
      progress = Math.round((params.value/150)*100);
      if(params.value===0){
        return '<div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; background: #ffffff color: #000000">'+params.value+'</div>';
      }
      else if(params.value<50 && params.value>0){
        return  '<div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; background: linear-gradient(to right, red '+progress+'%, transparent '+progress+'%); color: #000">'+params.value+'</div>';
      }
      else if(params.value>49 && params.value<70){
        return '<div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; background: linear-gradient(to right, orange '+progress+'%, transparent '+progress+'%); color: '+(progress > 55? "#fff":"#000")+'">'+params.value+'</div>';
      }
      else if(params.value>69 && params.value<100){
        return '<div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; background: linear-gradient(to right, #53bd9c '+progress+'%, transparent '+progress+'%); color: '+(progress > 55? "#fff":"#000")+'">'+params.value+'</div>';
      }
      else if(params.value>100){
        return '<div style="background: linear-gradient(to right, green '+progress+'%, transparent '+progress+'%); font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #fff">'+params.value+'</div>';
      }
    }
    else{
      let value = parseFloat(params.value);
      if(value<50){
        return '< 50';
      }
      else if(value>49 && value<70){
        return  '50 - 69';
      }
      else if(value>69 && value<101){
        return '70 - 100';
      }
      else if(value>100)
        return '100+';
    }
  }
```

AgGridReact component use:

`

```
<AgGridReact
  enableFilter = { true }
  enableSorting = { true }
  enableColResize = { true }
  onGridReady = { this.onGridReady.bind(this) }
  onFilterChanged = {this.filterChanged.bind(this)}
  frameworkComponents = {this.state.frameworkComponents}
  columnDefs = { this.state.columnDefs }
  rowData    = { this.state.rowDefs }
/>`
```

Ex.

row1  - value 11
row2  - value 30
row3  - value 55
row4  - value 110
row5  - value 135

So if you group these rows according to range mentioned above you should get this

<50(2),
50-100(1),
100+(2)

but i am getting this output

<50(1)
<50(1)
50-100(1)
100+(1)
100+(1)

Comment: cellRenderer doesn't do grouping

Comment: How to group then?

Comment: I have used valueKeyCreator to fic this issue. :)